# can't get child data from JSON to datatables

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I need to use angularjs datatables for showing JSON data gets from API, but my JSON have child object, and I can't get this data to table.
here is my json

```
{
"1009": {
    "id": 1009,
    "serial_number": "1009-U",
    "campaigns": {
        "52": {
            "id": 52,
            "name": "testSLOV"
        },
        "47": {
            "id": 47,
            "name": "IMA PODJELE"
        },
        "44": {
            "id": 44,
            "name": "TEST DUPLO"
        },
        "30": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "ag3"
        },
        "26": {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "fdgdfsg"
        }
    }
},
"1051": {
    "id": 1051,
    "serial_number": "1051-U",
    "campaigns": {
        "52": {
            "id": 52,
            "name": "testSLOV"
        },
        "43": {
            "id": 43,
            "name": "test weather"
        },
        "39": {
            "id": 39,
            "name": "default2"
        },
        "37": {
            "id": 37,
            "name": "ag5"
        }
    }
},
"1500": {
    "id": 1500,
    "serial_number": "1500-U",
    "campaigns": {
        "51": {
            "id": 51,
            "name": "ag10"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my ctrl

```
var vm = this;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
        url: 'url',
        type: 'GET'
    })
.withDataProp('data')
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('responsive', true)
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
 vm.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('Id'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('type').withTitle($translate('TYPE')),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('city').withTitle($translate('CITY')),
            ]
```

I try add this in ajax,

```
dataSrc: function ( d ) {
            angular.forEach(d, function(k, v){
                console.log(k); 
                return k;
            })
          },
```

In console i get data, but don't know how to get data from child to table in view.

Here is htm

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover" width="100%"></table>
```

I also try in newColumn add data.id but nothing happened.

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('data.id').withTitle('Id'),
```

I get error in console

> jquery.dataTables.min.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: There seems to be discrepancy between "id", "type", "city" and the sample JSON. Could you describe precisely which data you want to show how?

Comment: from this JSON, in first  I want to show ID and SERIAL_NUMBER and when to click on that data show in collapsable CAMPAIGNS data. Like here http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withResponsive